# How to ensure that java system property `user.timezone` is explicitly specified?

Tags: java, timezone, system-properties

I want to be sure that my Java program is always run by explicitly specified `user.timezone` property. I pass `-Duser.timezone=XXX` as a command-line setting.

However, when I omit that system property at all, and then in my program I check the value of `System.getProperty("user.timezone")`, it is not `null`, instead, it contains the system timezone. So, I can't terminate my program, as the value of that property is never null.

I know that I can use a custom system property name(say `tz`) to accept the timezone ID and then execute `TimeZone.setDefault(System.getProperty("tz"))` in my code, but I prefer to use the system property `user.timezone`, which is intended to be used for that reason.

Is there any way to achieve what I need using `user.timezone` system property ?

Comment: If it has a value it has a value. Why don't you accept the one that's already been set, even if it wasn't set manually? If that's not ok, just use a custom property.

Comment: I want to be sure that the value of that system property is explicitly set in order to avoid the case when it is forgotten to be set and the system timezone(which becomes my program's timezone in that case) is wrong

Comment: How exactly are you specifying that system property?

Comment: in CLI, using `-Duser.timezone=XXX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much agree with the answer by Basil Bourque: Your solution is to write your code so it is independent of a JVM default time zone. Also as mentioned in the comments, when using java.time types with your SQL database through JDBC 4.2 (or later), no default time zone interferes.

Furthermore from what I have read drivers tend to use the database session time zone, not the JVM default time zone. You may want to search your database documentation and your JDBC driver documentation for ways to control the session time zone.

However to answer your question as asked:

```
    String userTimezoneProp = System.getProperty("user.timezone");
    boolean timezonePropertyEmpty = userTimezoneProp == null || userTimezoneProp.isEmpty();
    if (timezonePropertyEmpty) {
        System.err.println("You must set the user.timezone property to the same time zone as the database time zone.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Only you must do this before doing any operations that use the default time zone. Once such an operation is performed, the JVM will query the operating system for a default time zone and set the system property accordingly (if successful).

According to the documentation `System.getProperty()` should return `null` for a system property that has not been set. My Java returned an empty string in this example. So I take both possibilities into account. It may be something special for `user.timezone`. I didn’t find any documentation mentioning it. I still do not guarantee that the method is bullet-proof.

Answer (score 6):

## Specify time zone explicitly as argument to method calls

Relying on the JVM’s current default time zone is inherently unreliable. Any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can, at any moment, change the default with a call to `TimeZone.setDefault`. Such a call immediately affects all other code relying on that default.

Instead, always specify explicitly the time zone you desire/expect.

Also, `TimeZone` is obsolete, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically, `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`. You can pass an object of those classes as an optional argument to all the relevant methods.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

## UTC is the one true time

On a server, generally the best practice is to set the default time zone of both the host OS and JVM to UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero).

And most of your business logic, logging, and debugging should all be in UTC as well.

A time zone should only be needed:

- When localizing display to the user.
- Where required by a particular business rule.

---

By the way, that property `user.timezone` is not listed as one of the [standard default properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) in Java 11.

Comment: even in your suggested approach, I think it is better to accept `Africa/Casablanca` using `user.timezone` system property so that JVM's default timezone is also set to `Africa/Casablanca`. Combining this with your approach, we will always explicitly specify the timezone we desire, but also we will have the default timezone set to the desired timezone, so that if accidentally one day a developer forgets to specify the timezone explicitly, relying on the default timezone, we will have less chances to introduce a bug. So in that case my original  question still remains actual

Comment: @SurenAznauryan Actually, on a server, generally the best proactive is to set the default time zone of both the host OS and JVM to UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero). And most of your business logic, logging, and debugging should all be in UTC as well. A time zone should only be involved for localizing display to the user and where required for a particular business rule. So there should not be hat many places in your code base to forget the time zone.

Comment: As you mentioned above, any code in any thread can change the JVM default timezone at any time, hence we should use the desired timezone explicitly whenever we need to operate with date and time. But even if we do that, still in case when some code changes the JVM default time zone , we get a problem of timezone divergence between JVM and DB which, as I remember, leads to a weird date and time conversions creating strange bugs. Maybe it will be a good practice to use a security manager to block `TimeZone.setDefault()` as well, what do you think ?

Comment: When exchanging *java.time* objects (not strings!) of a type appropriate to the type of the database column, you will encounter no time zone problems. This has been covered many many times on a Stack Overflow by me and others.